# Need help with the integral of marginal density function

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, density-function, marginal-distribution

The joint density of random variables X and Y is given by
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x} ,  & 0\le x \lt \infty \ , \ 0\le y \le x \\
0\quad , & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Compute $\text{Cov}(X ,Y)$.

So in order to get the covariance, I need to find the marginal density function for $x$ and $y$
first, then compute $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$.

I am able to get the marginal density function for $x$ but I am stucked with the marginal density function for $y$:
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\:dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x}\:dx
$$
The integral does not converge at $0$.

Or should I use $\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x}\:dx$ instead of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x}\:dx$ , since $0\le y \le x\lt \infty$ ?

But I am also not sure how to deal with $\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x}\:dx$...

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the domain is the infinite triangle region under the line $y=x$ and above the x-axis. So when you find the marginal function, your integration limit for $x$ is from $y$ to $\infty$

$$f_Y(y)=\int_y^\infty f(x,y) dx$$

This is exponential integral, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

You cannot proceed more from here to find an analytical result for $f_Y(y)$. But you still can calculate the $E(Y)$ for example, $$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty yf_Y(y)dy=\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty yf(x,y) dxdy$$

Interchange the integration orders:

$$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^x yf(x,y) dydx=\int_0^\infty\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x} \left(\int_0^x y dy\right)dx $$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you explain how should I integrate the f(x,y) please?

Comment: This is exponential integral, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral  but you still can calculate the $E(Y)$ for example, $$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty yf_Y(y)dy=\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty yf(x,y) dxdy$$

Comment: Oh... Didn't know that I could calculate E(Y) the other way. Thank you so much for saving my life!!! because I had been stucked at this question for hours T_T

Comment: haha, no worries :)